# Как создать указатель на функцию с параметрами по умолчанию?

Tags: c++

Нужно вызвать функцию из dll.
Пытаюсь создать указатель с последним параметром по умолчанию,но компилятор выдает ошибки.
Вот сам указатель :

```
 typedef double (*TEST)(double p, double T, const double ExtendComposition[],bool Check = false );
```

А вот ошибка :

```
default arguments are only permitted for function parameters [-fpermissive]
   typedef double (*TEST)(double p, double T, const double ExtendComposition[],bool = false );
```

Если аргументы по умолчанию разрешены только для функций,то как быть?

Comment: Что за указатель?  Вы создаете тип для указателей на функцию, принимающую такого то типа аргументы.  Это не объявление функции, что вы указываете аргумент по умолчанию или имена обьектов...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Оберните вызов вашей функции в другую функцию с параметром по-умолчанию.

Можно сделать `std::bind()` с 4 параметром, чтобы стало 3 аргумента

Comment: Не подходит такое решения.Дальше указатель на функцию из библиотеки передается в шаблон.Шаблон принимает еще и другие указатели на функции строго с тремя аргументами

Comment: @KostyaChernyaev обновил

Comment: @KostyaChernyaev, как это не подходит? Вы же сами хотите ф-ию с 3 параметрами, Вам это и предлагают.

Answer (score 1):

Почему не хотите просто написать правильно?

```
typedef double (*TEST)(double, double, const double [], bool);
```

Таким образом вы определяете тип для указателей на функцию с такими аргументами, а на какую функцию будут указывать экземпляры этого типа, это определению не касается.

Comment: Но мне то нужно что бы он указывал на ф-цию из библиотеки которая принимает 4 параметра.А вызывать ее с тремя параметрами (4ый по умолчанию)

Comment: Это  уже другая задача _  определять тип указателья на функцию с  разным количеством аргументов, которое решать с помощью typedef не получится